# Reading text file into linked list (error on print sequence)

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort

I have used `bubble sort` function to sort the linked list but the when I print 
its not   actually printing the list sorted.
Can you kindly show me the fault,so that I can go further:

Full  Running Program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct employee
{
char name[30];
char surname[30];
char address[30];
char cell[30];
struct emp *next;
}*start=NULL;

struct employee *new_node;
struct employee *current;
FILE *fp;

int main(char *argv[],int argc)
{
file_open();
printf("Before bubble sort:\n");
print_list(start);
printf("After  bubble sort:\n");
bubble_sort();
print_list(start);
return 0;
}

file_open()
{
char fname[20];
char line[128];
printf("ENTER THE FILE NAME:");
scanf("%s",fname);
fp=fopen(fname,"r");
if(fp != NULL)
{
    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp) != NULL)
    {
        //printf("FILE OPEN SUCCESSFULL");
        splitline(line);
        //printf("%s",line);
    }
    fclose ( fp );
}
else
{
    printf("ERROR OPEN FILE\n");
    return (1);
}
return 0;

}

 int splitline(char str[])
 {
 new_node=(struct employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
 char *store;
 store=strtok(str,", ");
 strcpy(new_node->name,store);
 store=strtok(NULL,", ");
 strcpy(new_node->surname,store);
 store=strtok(NULL,", ");
 strcpy(new_node->address,store);
 store=strtok(NULL,", ");
 strcpy(new_node->cell,store);
 new_node->next=NULL;

 if(start == 0)
 {
 start=new_node;
 current=new_node;
 }
 else
 {
current->next=new_node;
current=new_node;
 }
//print_list(current);
 return 0;
 }

 void print_list(struct employee *start)
 {
struct employee *ptr;
ptr=start;
while(ptr!=NULL)
{
printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",ptr->name,ptr->surname,ptr->address,ptr->cell);
ptr=ptr->next;
}
printf("\n");

}

void bubble_sort(struct employee *start)
{
struct employee *a = NULL;
struct employee *b = NULL;
struct employee *c = NULL;
struct employee *e = NULL;
struct employee *tmp = NULL;


while(e != start->next) {
c = a = start;
b = a->next;
while(a != e) {
if(a->name > b->name) {
if(a == start) {
 tmp = b -> next;
 b->next = a;
 a->next = tmp;
 start = b;
 c = b;
} else {
 tmp = b->next;
 b->next = a;
 a->next = tmp;
 c->next = b;
 c = b;
}
} else {
c = a;
a = a->next;
}
b = a->next;
if(b == e)
e = a;
}
}
```

}

Comment: Your bubble sort is not sorting anything, where are you comparing the names?? And you should not change the question like this. post another question with bubble sort. if you change the question totally, what will happen to the answers that addressed your previous queries? Post a new question with bubble sort and accept the answer that solved your problem. No body is going to answer you if you don't show gratefulness. If you don't know how to accept please read the FAQ page.

Comment: Sorry,I was actually trying to post in another section but could not work it well. But next time I will try to follow the instruction. Thank You for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You have copied same thing in every field.

```
strcpy(new_node->name,store);
strcpy(new_node->surname,store);
strcpy(new_node->address,store);
strcpy(new_node->cell,store);
```

You should marge your `splitline` and `create_node`.

```
int AddNodeFromLine(char str[])
{
new_node=(struct employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
new_node->next=NULL;
char *store;
store=strtok(str,", ");
strcpy(new_node->name,store);
store=strtok(NULL,", ");
strcpy(new_node->surname,store);
store=strtok(NULL,", ");
strcpy(new_node->address,store);
store=strtok(NULL,", ");
strcpy(new_node->cell,store);
new_node->next=NULL;

if(start == 0)
{
    start=new_node;
    current=new_node;
}
else
{
    current->next=new_node;
    current=new_node;
}
print_list(current);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey Dipto, Your answer really relieved me and understood. This program took me long time to solve. I was shucked. But now I can move on. And one thing more I just want to ask is that, I see you send current in print_list(current) but in main I send new_node in print_list(new_node). It does not conflict!

Comment: I Think, from main you should call `print_list(start)` to print the whole list. Both `print_list(current)` and `print_list(new_node)` will print the last node. Just try this to be sure.

Comment: Hi Dipto, I need your help once again. Actually now I want to sort the linked list first alphabetically and secondly according to number ascending order. Can you lead me there? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorting alphabetically is a complex task, Please read about it, search  and try to do it by yourself. then if you have any specific issue, post a new question with that. Solving that problem is not in the scope of this question. And if this answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: Okay, I will try it first then if I face any problem, I will ask you. I appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: I edited the program with the sort function. can you kindly check if you have time